# AWS CloudFormation StackSet fails with message "Attempt to perform create operation on already existing stack"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have 3 stack sets. I deploy them using the state machine. I want the state machine to be idempotent, to test this I invoke them with same inputs multiple times.

Initially, all 3 stack sets get deployed successfully.

On the second update, 2 of the 3 stack sets succeed, but the third one fails with error `Attempt to perform create operation on the already existing stack`.

Any idea why this might be happening?

I tried setting different client token/operation ID for the second attempt, but it still fails with the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening because the CFN template for failing stackset had NAMED resources (CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM). Templates with these type of resources can not be deployed in idempotent way. The solution was to invoke `CreateStackInstance` only if a stack instance does not already exist. Earlier, it used to invoked every single time by the state machine logic.

Comment: Can you explain more about this? I do an update to the stackset, passing list of accounts and the same `Attempt to perform create operation on the already existing stack` error happened on one of the existing instance. I don't understand why it complained about "create operation" here why I just do an update and the instance was present in the account list from before?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few reasons for that and more details can help to understand your issue.
Do you see more errors before the one you mentioned?

Mainly, try to follow this:
"Resources that are created as part of an AWS CloudFormation stack must be managed from the same stack. Modifications to a resource must be done by a stack update. If a resource is deleted, a stack update is also necessary to remove the resource from the template. If a resource has been accidentally or purposely manually deleted, you can encounter errors when attempting to perform a stack update."

Comment: My problem was due to attempt to deploy stack set that had named IAM resources. Templates with these type of resources can not be deployed in idempotent way.